# Params matching return empty React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am facing an apparently simple problem but it is getting complicating , even with some well written existing topics.

I have a global route

```
export const createPricingPath = `${catalogRoutes.priceLists.path}/creation/:pricingId?/:step(products|parameters|customers-groups)`;
export const toCreatePricingPath = pathToRegexp.compile(createPricingPath);
```

As you can see I have a step parameters and an optional one called pricingId.

I have a parent route leading to my top level parent component

```
    <ProtectedRoute
      exact
      AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.PRICING]}
      path={createPricingPath}
      render={props => <PricingCreationPanelContainer {...props} />}
    />
```

The parent top root component is the following one :

```
            <SlidePaneProvider route={catalogRoutes.priceLists.path}>
                {({ handleCancel }) => (
                    <Fragment>
                        <PricingCreationPanelHeader handleCancel={handleCancel} {...this.props} />
                        <SlidePaneBody>
                            <PricingContent handleCancel={handleCancel} {...this.props} />
                        </SlidePaneBody>
                    </Fragment>
                )}
            </SlidePaneProvider>
```

Inside this component we got somme "commun" elements like a PricingCreationHeader and SlidesComponents ( body ect...), and I have a PricingContent which is the children containing my sub-routes and children components.

It looks like this:

```
const PricingContent = ({ handleCancel, match: { params } }) => {

    return (
        <Switch>
            <ProtectedRoute
                exact
                AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.PRICING]}
                path={toCreatePricingPath({ step: 'parameters' })}
                render={props => <PricingCreation {...props} />}
            />
            <ProtectedRoute
                exact
                AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.PRICING]}
                path={toCreatePricingPath({ step: 'products', pricingId: params.pricingId })}
                render={props => <PricingProducts {...props} />}
            />
            <ProtectedRoute
                exact
                AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.PRICING]}
                path={toCreatePricingPath({ step: 'customers-groups', pricingId: params.pricingId })}
                render={props => <PricingClients handleCancel={handleCancel} {...props} />}
            />
        </Switch>
    )
};
```

The problem is, I can't figure out why I am not able to get the match.params.pricingId and match.params.step props inside every child component (PricingClients and PricingProducts ). PricingCreation doesnt need pricingId by the way, only the other two.

I do have the impression that everything is clearly well written.
The child component should be able to get all the params since the root parent component does.

Maybe it is an architecture problem so every suggestion is welcome !
I went through many existing topics and was not able to find a proper solution.

Thank you very much for helping me !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see here, path for child routes is specified incorrectly. I dont think that making path dynamically is a good idea. It is enough to specify shortened version of parent path and `match.pricingId` will be available in child components:

```
const PricingContent = ({ handleCancel }) => {

    return (
        <Switch>
            <ProtectedRoute
                path={ `${base_path }/creation/:pricingId?/parameters`}
                // other props stay the same
            />
            <ProtectedRoute
                path={ `${base_path}/creation/:pricingId?/products`}
               // other props stay the same
            />
            <ProtectedRoute
                path={ `${base_path}/creation/:pricingId?/customer-groups`}
               // other props stay the same
            />
        </Switch>
    )
};
```

According to code above `base_path` is `catalogRoutes.priceLists.path`.

1. I think there is no need in `:step` route param as we have a separate component for every route.
   In case we still need it, it's possible to do smt like this: `.../:step(parameters)`;
2. Optional `:pricingId?` can cause mounting of incorrect component, for example:
   `base_url/products/parameters`
   In this case router is considering "products" as `:pricingId` route param which is not good=)
   I often try to avoid optional params in the middle of a path

My apologies if I missed or misunderstood something
Thank you

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. Could you tell me which path is base_path is corresponding to ? And what if if the user is trying to access only base path url ?

Comment: Hi! I added annotation about `base_path` in my answer.

Comment: And what value do you mean by base path url?

Comment: I mean base_path/creation for example. If he hits that url what do we display ? Because with your solution, the url parent component ( the first one in my topic) would have base_path/creation as path right ?

Comment: Exactly, parent component does not require any route params, so that we can have `path={\`${base_path}/creation\`}` for parent route

Comment: Ok thank you very much. But what if we hit just base_path/creation in the url ? Directly in the url for example ?

Comment: According to your implementation, parent component will not be mounted at all (`:step` is required to match route), in case we hit `localhost://base_path/creation` directly in the browser address bar. I am not sure that I understand your question correctly =)

Comment: Let's say the parent component is base_path/creation. If the user navigates to it, it will start to looking for a matching path inside the switch statement. But what if the url is just base_path/creation and there is no matching path inside the switch. It will render the parent but no child right ?